# Why does my view get distorted?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uitoolbar

My view consists of a toolbar at the top and bottom of the view and an imageView in between.

I am adding subviews to my image view.

When a subview is added, the whole view sometimes becomes distorted.  The imageView will stretch, a toolbar and the bar button items shift as well.

What causes this?  Has anyone came across this before?

Suggestions to fixing this matter?

Note:  I have set up this view in Interface Builder, not programmatically.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using auto layout? Check if some constraints are set. http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Comment: @Rose OP answers that question in the original question.